# Possible interpretation for points of non equilibrium in a 2D ODE system where only one of the components of the vector field is $=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, vector-fields

I have a 2D ODE system
$$
x'=F(x),
$$ where $x=(x_1,x_2)$, i.e.,
$$
\begin{cases}x_1'(t)=F_1(x)\\
x_2'(t)=F_2(x);\end{cases}
$$
A component of the vector field $F$ I have vanishes at a point $x=(x_1,x_2)$, i.e. $F_2(x)=0$. If $F_1(x)=0$, then $x$ would be an equilibrium point. However, I only have $F_2(x)=0$: **can I still get some substantial information about the behavior of the solution $$
x(t)=\big(x_1(t), x_2(t)\big)
$$
around such points of $F(x)$**?

Many thanks.

Comment: This curve is a null-cline, one of the isocline curves (with the same inclination) of the vector field. They can be useful if you manually sketch a phase portrait, but I see nothing really "substantial".

Comment: @LutzLehmann, if you consider compose your useful comment into an answer I'll be happy to give you the bounty of the question. Thank you!